# Python complete ordering of a nested dict

Tags: python, nested, trie, ordereddictionary

I have some sort of trie composed of OrderedDicts (but in the wrong order) which looks like this:

```
    test = {
        'ab':{
            '1':{},
            '2':{
                '002':{},
                '001':{}}},
        'aa':{
            '02':{
                'ac':{},
                '01':{}, 
                'ca':{}, 
                'ab':{}},
            '01':{
                'b':{}, 
                'z':{
                    '0':{}, 
                    '1':{}}}}
    }
```

How can I get a complete ordering of this dict in all subsequent levels?

If I use ***collections.OrderedDict(sorted(test.iteritems()))*** I get it sorted only for the first level.

I feel that I need to create a function that it will somehow call itself recursively until the deepest level, but after I spent many hours trying different ways to solve the problem, I am still stuck here.

Eventually it has to look like this:

```
    test = {
        'aa':{
            '01':{
                'b':{}, 
                'z':{
                    '0':{}, 
                    '1':{}}},
            '02':{
                '01':{},
                'ab':{},
                'ac':{},
                'ca':{}}},

        'ab':{
            '1':{},
            '2':{
                '001':{},
                '002':{}}}
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the recursive function along with what's not working about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With recursion, remember there are two cases: the branch, and the leaf. Be sure to account for both.

```
def make_ordered(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return OrderedDict(sorted((key, make_ordered(value)) for key, value in d.iteritems()))
    else:
        return d
```

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. You just need to add parentheses after iteritems :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford an extra dependency I would recommend [blist package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/). It provides many sorted containers including `sorteddict`. Then your dictionary would just always stay sorted.

Check the [sorteddict class docs](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html) for exact usage. The package itself is production quality and BSD licence, so not a problem to use in any proprietary code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict as OD
def order(X):
    retval = OD()

    # The standard iterator of a dict is its keys.
    for k in sorted(X):
        # Incase it something we can't handle.
        if isinstance(X[k], dict):
            # I want my children dicts in order.
            retval[k] = order(X[k])
        else:
            retval[k] = X[k]

    return retval
```